# Dynamic update of rows according to indicators or states of other rows

Tags: sas

After a great help from this wonderful forum's members,
I made some progress with my program, 
but unfortunately I really need your help again...

I need to update a source table with delta rows.
problem is,
when RK already exists in target table, 
big chances is going to need an update of some variables.

Assuming target table is empy, I have a data similar to this which I calculate with a certain block of code:

```
DATA HAVE;
RK = 1;
VERSION = 0;
ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT ="01jan1990"d ;
ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT    = "01feb1990"d ;
POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT = "22feb1990"d ;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 1;
VERSION_EXPOSURE_DAYS_NO =30 ;
EXPOSED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT    = 12;
CALCULATED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT    = 4;
GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 8;
REMAINING_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 15;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_FX_V_AMT = 26;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_IB_V_AMT = 34;
DDS_ROW_IND = .;
CANCELLATION_IND = .;
FREEZED_IND =. ;
 STORNO_IND = .;
UNFREEZED_IND = .;
format ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT date9. ;
run;
```

Now, this row is inserted into target table on DDS.

When more rows of the same RK apears in source table, 
I take  all rows from taget table on DDS (1 row on this example) , flag it with DDS_ROW_IND = 1,
sort it and adds it to the whole calculations needed to be done;

Without making it to long or complex to read,
let's say another row of the same RK arrives to the source table:

```
DATA HAVE1;
RK = 1;
VERSION = 0;
ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT ="01jan1990"d ;
ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT    = "01feb1990"d ;
POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT = "22feb1990"d ;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 1;
VERSION_EXPOSURE_DAYS_NO =30 ;
EXPOSED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT    = 12;
CALCULATED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT    = 4;
GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 8;
REMAINING_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 15;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_FX_V_AMT = 26;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_IB_V_AMT = 34;
DDS_ROW_IND = 1;
CANCELLATION_IND = .;
FREEZED_IND =. ;
STORNO_IND = .;
UNFREEZED_IND = .;

output;

RK = 1;
VERSION = 1;
ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT ="01feb1990"d ;
ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT    = "19mar1990"d ;
POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT = "22apr1990"d ;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 8;
VERSION_EXPOSURE_DAYS_NO =1 ;
EXPOSED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT    = 5;
CALCULATED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT    =3;
GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 1;
REMAINING_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 6;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_FX_V_AMT = 44;
ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_IB_V_AMT = 8;
DDS_ROW_IND = 0;
CANCELLATION_IND = 1;
FREEZED_IND =. ;
STORNO_IND = .;
UNFREEZED_IND = .;
output;
format ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT date9. ;
run;
```

Note I updated DDS_ROW_IND on first row to equal 1;

Now,
because second row has variable CANCELLATION_IND = 1, 
let's say I need to cancel some logic from previous row,
re calculate it and retain the result.

for example,
variable ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT should be the result of POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT of the second row, Minus ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT of the first row, and GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT should be equal to the outcome of ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT / ACT_DAILY_NET_PREMIUM_FX_V_AMT and should be retained.
and let's say,
the next delta (third row) has an indicator STORNO_IND = 1 that basically says second row is a mistake,
let's undo the calculation made so far...

Bear in mind I have like 8 different states (indicators) and some of them simply cancells the others...

What's more,
second row and third row can apear together in source table, and can apear seperately, each of them on a different run...

Could someone give me a hint how to start writing this task....?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us a sample data set? Perhaps a more simplified version of your data with less variables. Because right now it's hard to picture what's going on.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd suggest separating the insertion and recalculation out into separate data steps - it'll be easier to re-do retain-based calculations once you have a dataset with all the right rows in the right order.